# Upgrading from Sequelize 4.41 to 5.8.5

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I need to upgrade a node app with Sequelize 4.41 to Sequelize 5.8.5 in order to fix the SQL injection vulnerability -- I'm assuming there need to be some code changes, but I'm pretty new to Node and Sequelize, how do I go about finding what needs to be changed syntactically in order for the app to work?

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade docs can be found [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/upgrade-to-v5.html).  Thankfully, it's fairly straightforward, with a lot of the changes being made to very niche features.

The main issue I had upgrading was with Sequelize operators:

> In v5 aliases has been removed from Sequelize prototype

```
// This no longer works
sequelize.Op.and

// Use this instead
Sequelize.Op.and
```

Comment: What would be the best way to determine which points of the code are breaking and need to be updated? The node app is pretty big, and I am having trouble finding the exact points of error.

Comment: any ideas as to how the best way about this is?